# Visual studio creating an enum file in local folder automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an Enum file in one of my projects. It contains many enums. Whenever I press F12 on any of the references to these enums in other projects, a file is created in AppData/Local/Temp/.... folder for that enum.
I tried deleting the file but it gets generated again if I try going to Enum definition.

Now, the major problem here is that I made changes to one of these enums but it doesn't reflect in its local enum file.

I have following two questions:

1. How and why does Visual studio create these local files?
2. Why is enum value not updated in that local file? I checked the Enum project reference in other projects. It is pointing to the updated dll.

And it stopped doing this after I restarted my Visual Studio. Now, I am just curious to know why was that happening? Is a Visual Studio feature?

Comment: I've seen this happen with ReSharper when I do this on external references/types (like `DataTable`, `bool`, etc.), but this seems totally different.

Comment: "_Is a Visual Studio feature?_" Seems to be more of a bug.

Comment: Instead of adding reference of project you would have added reference to compiled library/dll, so when ever you navigate to type present in referenced library then visual studio will fetch type information(metadata) from that library and generate temp file in order to list parameter/methods of navigated type.

Comment: @AnandChapla Yes I have added reference to compiled dll. But if that's the case, then, why isn't it happening now after I restarted VS?

Comment: @AnandChapla Also, is this behavior documented anywhere? A link would be very helpful.

Comment: @SachinParashar, did the compiled dll you create by yourself? As usual, we only will see all the define when we press F12. Maybe some code can help us to understand your problem clearly.